# Equivalent definition of a universal measure zero set.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, set-theory

I am studying Richard Laver's "On the consistency of Borel's conjecture" and i came across this definition and i need a little bit of help with it's equivalent form.

---

> X has universal measure zero if $f[X]$ has Lebesgue measure zero for each homeomorphism $f:[0, 1] \rightarrow [0, 1]$, equivalently, for each nonatomic, nonnegative, real valued Baire measure $\mu$ on $[0, 1]$, $\mu (X) = 0$.

---

Now i am stuck here and i think i need to study a bit more of analysis and i would really appreciate any good references related to this paper(atleast the parts related to analysis and measure theory). Also i would be really glad if someone could point me in the right direction with this equivalence.
Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Which part of the equivalence do you find difficult?

Comment: Both parts because i can't relate measures to homeomorphisms.

Comment: If you have a homeomorphism $f$, $\mu(X)=m(f^{-1}(X))$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. Show that $\mu$ Is a measure.

Comment: So if i prove this i think i can show the converse easily. And now for the other direction can i prove something like: given a measure $\mu$ i can find a homeomorphism $f$ such that $\mu (X) = m(f^{-1}(X))$? Or do i need to do something else?

Comment: I have never actually proved this equivalence, nor I have checked the details. The previous suggestion was just a suggestion as to how to head towards a solution, if I had to write a proof myself. But yes, to your last comment, that would be the approach I'd take. I'm sure there is some theorem that you can use to get that part done quicker.

Comment: Ok, thanks, and one more thing that i would like to ask: how much analysis do you think is needed to study this paper? (Like in terms of some chapters of a book)

Comment: I've never looked at the paper, so I don't know. I believe a fair amount of basic measure theory is probably good to have under your belt when you want to read about Borel's conjecture.

Comment: Pages 201-202 of Section IV of Brown/Cox's 1982 survey paper [*Classical theory of totally imperfect spaces*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44153408) says that proofs for the equivalence of 5 characterizations of universal measure zero sets (includes what you want) "*was given in the "Annex" to Vol. I of Fund. Math., which was written in 1937 by S. Braun and E. Spilrajn-Marczewski in collaboration with C. Kuratowski.*" Also relevant is pp. 212-213 of Section 5 of Arnold W. Miller's *Special subsets of the real line* in **Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology** (1984).

Comment: @Dave, Thank you very much!